# Spring MVC Rest unable to return JPEG with "could not find acceptable representation error"

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot app acting as a image server.  I POST an image to be persisted to mongodb.  I then retrieve it, resize and return it.

Here is the project configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class AllResources extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer matcher) {
        matcher.setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(true);
    }
}
```

And here is the endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "images/{filename}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<BufferedImage> getSizedImage(@PathVariable String filename, @RequestParam int width, @RequestParam int height) throws Exception {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);

    GridFSDBFile savedFile = mongoFileService.getStore( filename );

    if ( savedFile != null ) {
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read( savedFile.getInputStream() );
            image = resize( image, Method.SPEED, width, height, Scalr.OP_ANTIALIAS );

            LOGGER.info("Returning Filename " + savedFile.getFilename() + " sized to " + width + " X " + height);

            return new ResponseEntity<BufferedImage>(image, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch ( Exception ex ) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            LOGGER.error( "Error sizing file " + filename + ": " + ex.getMessage() );
            return new ResponseEntity<BufferedImage>(null, headers, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    } else {
        LOGGER.error( "Could not find requested file " + filename );
        return new ResponseEntity<BufferedImage>(null, headers, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

The image is retrieved and resized (I can actually preview when debugging in IntelliJ).  But when it is returned, I get the following error:

```
Controller [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController]
Method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]

org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:195)
```

And I see this in the logs:

```
Method [error] returned [<406 Not Acceptable,{timestamp=Sat Aug 22 11:05:59 MDT 2015, status=406, error=Not Acceptable, exception=org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException, message=Could not find acceptable representation, path=/images/1440263145562_profile_04132015.PNG},{}>]
2015-08-22 11:05:59.711 DEBUG 2478 --- [0.1-3000-exec-3] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Written [{timestamp=Sat Aug 22 11:05:59 MDT 2015, status=406, error=Not Acceptable, exception=org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException, message=Could not find acceptable representation, path=/images/1440263145562_profile_04132015.PNG}] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@5bf1ba3a]
2015-08-22 11:05:59.711 DEBUG 2478 --- [0.1-3000-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
```

I have tried with & without the @ResponseBody and it doesn't appear to make a difference either. I have the produces and content type set correctly (I think).

I added these converters (although I thought SpringBoot provided these), but to no avail:

```
@Configuration
public class AllResources extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer matcher) {
        matcher.setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(true);
    }
    @Bean
    public ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter byteArrayHttpMessageConverter(){
        ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter bam = new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter();
        List<org.springframework.http.MediaType> mediaTypes = new LinkedList<MediaType>();
        mediaTypes.add(org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        mediaTypes.add(org.springframework.http.MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
        mediaTypes.add(org.springframework.http.MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
        mediaTypes.add(org.springframework.http.MediaType.IMAGE_GIF);
        mediaTypes.add(org.springframework.http.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        bam.setSupportedMediaTypes(mediaTypes);
        return bam;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mapper = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converters.add(mapper);
        converters.add(byteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```

I hope someone can see what is causing this issue.

Comment: Hi dude. Make your title of question to be some more common problem or Error name that u faced. So that more people will visit..u may get lot of reputations..Hope u understand what I said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this piece of code

```
@RequestMapping("/sparklr/photos/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<BufferedImage> photo(@PathVariable String id) throws Exception {
    InputStream photo = sparklrService.loadSparklrPhoto(id);
    if (photo == null) {
        throw new UnavailableException("The requested photo does not exist");
    }
    BufferedImage body;
    MediaType contentType = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG;
    Iterator<ImageReader> imageReaders = ImageIO.getImageReadersByMIMEType(contentType.toString());
    if (imageReaders.hasNext()) {
        ImageReader imageReader = imageReaders.next();
        ImageReadParam irp = imageReader.getDefaultReadParam();
        imageReader.setInput(new MemoryCacheImageInputStream(photo), true);
        body = imageReader.read(0, irp);
    } else {
        throw new HttpMessageNotReadableException("Could not find javax.imageio.ImageReader for Content-Type ["
                + contentType + "]");
    }
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
    return new ResponseEntity<BufferedImage>(body, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**EDIT:**
We have to configure MessageConverter

```
@Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter());
    }
```

Here I have Content Negotiator like this

```
@Bean
public ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentViewResolver() throws Exception {
    ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentViewResolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
    ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean contentNegotiationManager = new ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean();
    contentNegotiationManager.addMediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    contentViewResolver.setContentNegotiationManager(contentNegotiationManager.getObject());
    contentViewResolver.setDefaultViews(Arrays.<View> asList(new MappingJackson2JsonView()));
    return contentViewResolver;
}
```

I think the message inside your logs can clear your doubts. Have a close look at your logs and comment me again

Comment: I updated my question with the changes you suggested.   I still get the same error.  Do I need to register a handler for BufferedImage?

Comment: Thank you!  I had incorrectly assumed Spring-Boot was loading the message converters.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that none of the registered message converters knows how to write a `BufferedImage` to the response in the format dictated by the accept header. Try registering your own message converter that knows how to write out a `BufferedImage` in the requested format.

Comment: I added message converters, but they don't seem to help.